# Was the intro for The Expanse inspired by Game of Thrones

Tags: game-of-thrones, the-expanse-2015

The intro to The Expanse reminds me to the intro of Game of Thrones

Intro of The Expanse

Intro of Game of Thrones

Both intros show important places, buildings "growing" and none of the main characters directly. Maybe it's just me, but it seems to me that The Expanse intro was inspired by the one from Game of Thrones. Has this ever been addressed and confirmed / denied by somebody involved in Expanse?

Comment: https://brief.promax.org/article/design-dissect-the-expanse-show-open - No mention here

Comment: +1 Shade I have a friend who made a similar point about the opening of season 1 of *ST: Discovery* and *GoT*… I suspect that the folks at HBO expressed something that influenced the style of several other shows over the past decade. :)

Comment: "Growing" elements has become common in other CGI intros as well as the algorithms to run them become more widely available. I've seen it in a few Euro shows.

Comment: @jeffronicus see also Westworld intros

Comment: This goes all the way back to the _Star Wars_ vector arcade game.

Answer (score 5):

While this is not conclusive evidence the two shows shared 43 people in the visual effects department. However, some worked on *Game of Thrones* first but others worked on *The Expanse* first. I also don't know what specific parts of the show the people worked, and none seem to have been around at the start of *Game of Thrones* in 2011.

I think it is more likely that the VFX company they worked for worked on both shows. These companies and/or people probably shared design elements and processes and brought elements from the *Game of Thrones* intro to *The Expanse*. It's kind of a stretch but it is a connection...

| Name | GoT Years | Expanse Years |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Neishaw Ali | 2013 | 2017-2019 |
| Siubhan Smith | 2019 | 2017 |
| Daniel Pons | 2019 | 2017 |
| Wendy Lanning | 2014 | 2021-2022 |
| Jerry Seguin | 2013 | 2017-2018 |
| Ahmed Shehata | 2013 | 2015-2016 |
| Adam Tamblyn | 2019 | 2021 |
| Ranajoy Kar | 2016 | 2021 |
| Adam Jewett | 2013 | 2015-2016 |
| Patrick Zentis | 2013 | 2015 |
| Garloff Langenbeck | 2015 | 2017-2019 |
| Tim M. Townsend | 2013 | 2017-2021 |
| Brandon Terry | 2013 | 2015-2016 |
| Lee Zhu | 2019 | 2020 |
| Douglas Addy | 2013 | 2015-2016 |
| Geoff Sayer | 2013 | 2015-2022 |
| Zhiying Song | 2019 | 2018 |
| Tim Sibley | 2013 | 2015-2021 |
| Ehsan Ramezani | 2019 | 2021-2022 |
| Rahul Saxena | 2019 | 2018 |
| Kirk Brillon | 2013 | 2015-2018 |
| Sunny Wong | 2013-2019 | 2019 |
| David Raymond | 2017 | 2017-2018 |
| Winston Lee | 2013 | 2015-2018 |
| Asim Khan | 2013 | 2015-2017 |
| Charles Angus Taylor | 2013 | 2015-2016 |
| Emmanuel Dirian | 2017 | 2018 |
| Peter Bas | 2013 | 2019 |
| Jason Kozsurek | 2013 | 2017 |
| Jongju Lee | 2011-2013 | 2015-2018 |
| Adreanne Lamoureux | 2015-2016 | 2017-2018 |
| James Chretien | 2013 | 2015-2016 |
| Patrick Gagnon | 2017 | 2018 |
| Che Yen Chuang | 2017 | 2020-2021 |
| Amanda Hollingworth | 2013-2019 | 2019 |
| Richard Chiu | 2013 | 2016-2019 |
| Danny R. Dixon | 2013 | 2018 |
| Christian Boudman | 2013-2019 | 2020-2021 |
| Florence Dubin | 2015 | 2016 |
| Fiaz Shaikh | 2014 | 2021 |
| Richard Noun | 2019 | 2021-2022 |
| Ralph Reinle | 2013 | 2020-2021 |
| [**Source**](https://www.imdb.com/search/name/?roles=tt0944947,tt3230854&ref_=rlm) |  |  |